# fragment shader distance precision

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

I have a problem with my fragment shader. I want to implement per frament lighting in 2d. I use `distance` function to measure distance to light source. to It works fine if my object is near to origin (0, 0). If my object is away from there (let's say (5000, 0)) then I have imprecision which is very visible. I tried `highp` but it didn't help. Which is a good way to measure distance from arbitrary point in model coordinates to fragment?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that its not to do with the precision of the variable. [This Opengl reference](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) on page 32 shows that (5000, 0) is well within its range. I think you are overlooking something

Comment: @Fonix I've solved the initial problem by calculating distances per vertix and then writing the result to varying. In this case it works fine enough. But I'm still wondering why it is not working correctly in fragment shader.

Comment: hard to tell what could be wrong without seeing some code, you might get more help if you step us through your code